# Javascript for loop with array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

Trying to fetch and display data from an array in a for loop but it's only showing one entry.  I'm executing this in a trigger for Storyline and when viewing Storyline in the browser I don't get any help from the inspector.

```
function showInfo(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var player = GetPlayer();
        player.SetVar("name", data[0].name + "\n");
    }
}
```

Seems like something simple to do but not sure whats going on.  Perhaps Articulate Storyline adds an extra layer of issues not forseen.

Comment: could you debug your javascript code and see ?

Comment: Seems like you are doing 'data[0]' instead of 'data[i]'

Comment: You are using `data[0]` instead of `data[i]` inside the loop

Comment: Not sure why OP got downvoted.  It's obvious they're new to SO and made a simple oversight.

Comment: @jusopi I somewhat see why it got downvoted. However I agree. There's some people on here who it appears gets a fetish from downvoting people. We should be bringing each other up, not down.

Comment: Hello all for your help.  it appears you were correct about changing the `0` to `i`.  Another quick question, is it correct to declare a variable inside the `for` loop or should it be initialized outside the `for` loop.

Comment: @OscarArango Depends how/when you're using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`but it's only showing one entry`

this is because you're accessing at `0` index for each. You need to use `i` to correctly iterate over every element.

see:

```
function showInfo(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var player = GetPlayer();
        player.SetVar("name", data[i].name + "\n");
    }
}
```